# How to get last value before current Window during Flink reduce calculation

Tags: apache-flink

I'm using Flink 1.6 timeWindow. Assuming I have following data point:

Timestamp, Value

***12:55:00, 10***

**13:05:00, 12**

**13:30:00, 14**

**13:59:00, 13**

14:02:00, 17

Now, my timewindow is 13:00(inclusive) ~ 14:00 (exclusive), how can I get the last value, which is 12:55:00, 10, as an initial value for current Window calculation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Broadly speaking, there are two ways you can approach this:

1. some sort of custom windowing
2. use a ProcessFunction instead

Given the way that the window API is designed, I don't see any way to accomplish this while using pre-aggregation (i.e., reduce or aggregate), but I think you could do something with a ProcessWindowFunction and a custom Evictor, or by leveraging the globalState in ProcessWindowFunction.Context to keep state between one window and the next.

One issue you might run into is that if no events fall into the hour for 13:00 ~ 14:00, for example, then no window will be created or evaluated. If that's a problem, then further customization is needed.

In most cases involving non-standard windowing, it's more straightforward and more performant to use a ProcessFunction. That way you have direct control over what state to keep, and the window triggering logic generally isn't very difficult to recreate.

Comment: thank you, David. indeed, you pointed out another question I'm struggling with. Nowadays, sensor usually will be designed or configured to emit data only when changed. If sensor doesn't have data value changed from 12:55:00 till 14:05:00, yes, how to handle window for 13:00 ~ 14:00 is a challenge. I haven't figured out how to handle this yet in Flink. Output is still required for 13:00~14:00 even there is no event coming in with timestamp between that.

Comment: Hi, David, jus a follow up. I use ProcessFunction and it meets my expectation. Meanwhile, I use onTimer on top of ProcessTime to trigger periodical scheduler even without new event comes in. thanks again for your sharing and it really helps.